# /system/console/configMgr in CRX / AEM

Tags: apache, authentication, aem, crx

Is it possible to change the settings of the Apache Authentication module in the (/system/console/configMgr) config manager? I'd like to turn off "allow anonymous access" but due to config issues the anonymous access required to access the login screen has been disabled. I'm assuming this could be done via cURL somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. 
The following cUrl statement does the trick for me, restores the sling.auth.requirements settings and disables anonymous access.

```
curl -u admin:admin 'http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.engine.impl.auth.SlingAuthenticator' --data 'apply=true&action=ajaxConfigManager&%24location=launchpad%3Aresources%2Finstall%2F19%2Forg.apache.sling.auth.core-1.3.6.jar&auth.sudo.cookie=sling.sudo&auth.sudo.parameter=sudo&auth.annonymous=false&sling.auth.requirements=%2B%2F&sling.auth.requirements=-%2Flibs%2Fgranite%2Fcore%2Fcontent%2Flogin&sling.auth.requirements=-%2Fetc%2Fclientlibs%2Fgranite&sling.auth.anonymous.user=&sling.auth.anonymous.password=unmodified&auth.http=preemptive&auth.http.realm=Sling+(Development)&auth.uri.suffix=%2Fj_security_check&propertylist=auth.sudo.cookie%2Cauth.sudo.parameter%2Cauth.annonymous%2Csling.auth.requirements%2Csling.auth.anonymous.user%2Csling.auth.anonymous.password%2Cauth.http%2Cauth.http.realm%2Cauth.uri.suffix'
```

Comment: Thomas, you have totally saved my behind on this one.

Comment: I can get into the configMgr screen now and login for AEM resources is working but I'm still receiving an error related to the anonymous account when I try to get to any forms or the root "/lc": 27.12.2015 06:30:31.909 *WARN* [127.0.0.1 [1451215831909] GET /lc/ws HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.fd.core.security.internal.CurrentUserServiceImpl Not able to find user for userId [anonymous]

Comment: Is the user still there? Can you check in useradmin?